# How to properly override Runnable.run(), so it can take parameters?

Tags: java, android, overriding, runnable

I am currently working on an android project and came across the situation, that I have to pass a function as parameter, so I browsed StackOverflow and tried out solution, to encapsulate the function with a `Runnable`.

The problem I'm now facing is, that the function I want to pass, expects parameters and `Runnable.run()` doesn't take any. So I'm currently trying to extend `Runnable` and override `run()` to let it accept parameters, which I can then pass to the actual function.

Now I'm kinda unsure, as `run()` is used in `Thread` on how I can override it, without knocking out `Thread`. I don't use any other `Thread` methods so far. Any suggested approach?

**EDIT**

The target is, to call these custom Runnables inside a listener method like so:

```
public void startRequest(RequestOperation operation, final Runnable onSuccess, final Runnable onError, final Runnable onFinished) {

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, instance_context.getResources().getString(R.string.base_url), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            onSuccess.run();
            onFinished.run();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            onError.run();
            onFinished.run();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}
```

In best case, `onSuccess` is able get the `response` object passed, as `onError` gets the `error`.

Comment: not. overriding a method (or implementing it) means you'll take the exact same method signature, which includes the parameters.

Comment: You could use Java's Consumer, that takes one argument and is similar to Runnable a functional interface.

Comment: @Stultuske is there by any chance a way to wrap the actual method inside the `run()`then?

Comment: One way to resolve it is to implement the `Runnable` interface and add the `response` as a field of the class.

Comment: @AndrianekenaMoise I was thinking exactly in that way :D, currently trying that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why force `Runnable` into being something it's not designed to be?
Simply have your own interface that has the signature you require.
E.g.

```
public interface Callback<T> {
    void run(T parameter);
}

public void startRequest(RequestOperation operation, final Callback<JSONObject> onSuccess, final Callback<VolleyError> onError, final Runnable onFinished) {

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, instance_context.getResources().getString(R.string.base_url), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            onSuccess.run(response);
            onFinished.run();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            onError.run(error);
            onFinished.run();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Or even better (if you ask me):

```
public interface Callback {
    void onSucces(JSONObject response);
    void onError(VolleyError error);
    void onFinished();
}

public void startRequest(RequestOperation operation, final Callback callback) {

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, instance_context.getResources().getString(R.string.base_url), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            callback.onSuccess(response);
            callback.onFinished();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            callback.onError(error);
            callback.onFinished();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}
```

You can also make `Callback` generic again, if you need to:

```
public interface Callback<R, E> {
    void onSucces(R response);
    void onError(E error);
    void onFinished();
}

public void startRequest(RequestOperation operation, final Callback<JSONObject, VolleyError> callback) {...}
```

To use:

```
public class SimpleCallback implements Callback {
    public void onSucces(JSONObject response) {
        doSomethingWithResponse(response);
    }

    public void onError(VolleyError error) {
        doSomethingWithError(error);
    }

    void onFinished() {
        logFinishTime();
    }
}

startRequest(operation, new SimpleCallback());
```

Comment: That's pretty much, what I had in mind. So in order to define the explicit content of `onSuccess` / `onError` / `onFinished` inside the components that call the `startRequest` method, they have to implement the interface then?

Comment: @procra Updated the answer. You of course have to provide an implementation of `Callback`, just like you'd have to provide an implementation of `Runnable`.